# How to minus amount with this condition?

Tags: google-sheets

Please see:
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/dilKgPz3xoPUhPjTLK3Tq0YcE5xxir4pHZ4", "My Balance!C21")

So this is giving result as 30000
But I want to append minus sign, so expected result should be -30000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply place a minus sign in front of the function:

```
=-IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/dilKgPz3xoPUhPjTLK3Tq0YcE5xxir4pHZ4", "My Balance!C21")
```